# Foreign Key CASCADE DELETE for table with multiple parents?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, cascade, cascading-deletes

I am very new to foreign keys and CASCADE operations, and am wondering about the following scenario:

Let's say I have two completely different parent tables (HUMAN and ALIEN) with completely different data. Now, what I want to do is create a child table named SPACESHIP, as both humans and aliens can own spaceships, with an FK that would point to either a row in HUMAN or a row in ALIEN, in the hopes that if I delete either a human row or an alien row, it would Cascade Delete the corresponding spaceship rows owned by the respective parent. Is there a good way to do this with FK's and CASCADE DELETE? Or should I just have a column in HUMAN and ALIEN called `spaceship_id` and handle the delete of spaceships manually / via trigger? Some other course of action?

Help!

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by adding a supertype table (lets call it `Being`) that has as subtypes the two `Human` and `Alien` tables. Then the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint would reference this superype table.

The supertype:

```
CREATE TABLE Being
( BeingId  INT AUTO_INCREMENT
, ... other stuff about beings
, PRIMARY KEY (BeingId)
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

the subtypes:

```
CREATE TABLE Human
( BeingId  INT                           --- not AUTO_INCREMENT
, ... other stuff about humans
, PRIMARY KEY (BeingId)
, CONSTRAINT Being_Human_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (BeingId)
      REFERENCES Being(BeingId)
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE Alien
( BeingId  INT                           --- not AUTO_INCREMENT
, ... other stuff about aliens
, PRIMARY KEY (BeingId)
, CONSTRAINT Being_Alien_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (BeingId)
      REFERENCES Being(BeingId)
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

and the `Spaceship` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Spaceship
( SpaceshipId
, SpaceshipName
, OwnerId
, ... other stuff about spaceships
, PRIMARY KEY (SpaceshipId)
, CONSTRAINT Being_Spaceship_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (OwnerId)
      REFERENCES Being(BeingId)
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

Comment: thanks, I have done things like this before; I don't know if I can use this strategy in my current project (examples aren't exactly HUMAN and ALIEN, they are actually already descended from such a table) but I'll try rethinking this, thanks

Comment: Disappointed. I thought you were creating some Star Trek game :(

Answer (score 0):

If you use [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) storage engine, then you can use foreign keys, because currently only InnoDB supports them. Otherwise you can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html) or delete parent and child records using one query, e.g.:

```
DELETE HUMAN, SPACESHIP
 FROM HUMAN
 JOIN SPACESHIP
   ON HUMAN.id = SPACESHIP.id
WHERE HUMAN.id = 1;
```